# Bud Spencer Terrence Hill - Hits Sound Design

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

how where those sounds made? Some sound like hefty reverbed claps some sound like foley some like white noise or extremely distorted foley.

Do you have some information on those?

Thanks,
Tobi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They hit meat (side of pork/beef, hams) with belts - as far as I remember correctly :)

Comment: Haha i have to try that :D

Comment: I think it comes pretty close. Combined with the typical saturation effects of the gear back then it might be it!